# How to make a rating bar show only full stars

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a rating bar's progress to show only full stars. That means if I set the progress at 1.1, it will show ONLY 1 STAR. How can I do that?

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBarSendReview"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:progressTint="@color/valet_hop_gold"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/menuTitleReview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: If you did find the solution to your question you should accept the correct answer. So that others can be sure it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
android:stepSize="0.5"
```

to

```
android:stepSize="1"
```

Now Rating can be  `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

Answer (score 0):

Step size being set to 1.0 means that it will only increment in whole star intervals. If you would like that to happen, change 0.5 to 1.0.